# WBXML Parser/decoder

Tags: java, android, wbxml

As the title suggest I'm looking for a WBXML Parser/decoder for Java(+Android) that follow version 1.3. I could even consider calling native code if that's necessarily.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do remember that some time ago I used the Java library kxml or kxml2 for parsing WBXML files.

Comment: I've tried that. But I could only get it to work with WBXML 1.2.

Comment: My bad. kXML supports 1.3. I only have to fill in all the tag tables.